# I use vue-tel-input in vue 3 project but when i build project there is problem

Tags: vuejs3

I downloaded vue-tel-input and all is good in 'npm run serve' but when i build a project there is a problem:

vite v4.4.7 building for production...
✓ 3 modules transformed.
✓ built in 309ms
[vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "vue3-tel-input" from "/Users/o2/projects/sportup-front/src/main.js".
This is most likely unintended because it can break your application at runtime.
If you do want to externalize this module explicitly add it to
`build.rollupOptions.external`
error during build:
Error: [vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "vue3-tel-input" from "/Users/o2/projects/sportup-front/src/main.js".
This is most likely unintended because it can break your application at runtime.
If you do want to externalize this module explicitly add it to
`build.rollupOptions.external`

what to do to resolve it?

did someone tried to resolve it? i tried to resolve a problem but i didnt find out how i can do it

Comment: i added   build: {
   rollupOptions: {
    external: ['vue3-tel-input'],
   },
  },
but it doesnt help